# CloudFormation cross-stack reference pass variables between root stack and child stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My goal is to create a **root stack** that passes the `stack-name` value to the **child stack**, then the **child stack** creates the DynamoDB table with the Table name: `stack-name-dynamodb-table`. I'm trying to make the `dynamodb.json` template reusable. So if it's like code, I'd like to do something similar to this:

```
const createDynamoDB = require('createDynamoDB');
fucntion main(stackName) {
  createDynamoDB(stackName);
  createOtherResources(stackName);
}
```

reusable function:

```
function createDynamoDB(name) {
  const tableName = `${name}-table`;
  // create the table with tableName
}
```

I'm stuck in a **chicken and egg** situation:

My `root-stack1`:

```
"Parameters": {
        "DatabaseStack": {
            "Description": "The database stack that creates DynamoDB table.",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength" : 1,
            "MaxLength" : 255,
            "AllowedPattern" : "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$",
            "Default" : "dynamodb1"
        }
    },

    "Resources": {
        "Database": {
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Properties": {
                "Fn::ImportValue" :  {"Fn::Sub": "${DatabaseStack}-DynamoDBProperties" }
            }
        }
    },

    "Outputs": {
        "DatabaseName" : {
            "Value" : {
                "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-table"
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-table"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My `dynamodb1`:

```
    "Parameters": {
        "RootStack": {
            "Description": "The root stack that controls all templates.",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength" : 1,
            "MaxLength" : 255,
            "AllowedPattern" : "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$",
            "Default" : "root-stack1"
        }
    },

    "Resources": {
        "DDBTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Properties": {
                "TableName": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue" :  {"Fn::Sub": "${RootStack}-DatabaseName" }
                },
                "AttributeDefinitions": [
                    ...
    "Outputs": {
        "DynamoDBProperties": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "DDBTable",
                    "Properties"
                ]
            },
            "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["DDBTable", "TableName"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is when I run create-stack using the root-stack1 I get this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Expected an object, received {"Fn::ImportValue":{"Fn::Sub":"${DatabaseStack}-DynamoDBProperties"}}
```

How do I pass the whole properties of the DynamoDB table which is created in the `dynamodb.json` template to the `root-stack.json` template?

Do I have to describe the DynamoDB table properties again? If yes, that seems redundant. The goal is to reuse the `dynamodb.json` template so in the future, if I need to create a table with the same schema, I can just reference it in a new root-stack with new stack-name.

Comment: And the issue is....?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me update my question.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a table in both stacks? Why not create the tables in the child stack?

Comment: I'm trying to create the table in the child stack. I just need the child stack that creates the table to get the `StackName` from the parent. I don't really know how to manage the `Resources` in the parent stack.

Comment: Why is the parent stack  trying to get a value from the child stack? Why not move the `Table` in root stack to the dynamo-stack

Comment: That's a good question. So what do I put into the `Resources` in the `root-stack` since it's a required property of a template?

Comment: `Resources` can be an empty list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193472/discussion-between-viet-and-rdas).

Comment: Although, to simplify things you might wanna put everything in one stack. That'll simplify things

Comment: My goal is to make the resources reusable. If I put everything in one template (includes other resources, the template will be massive). Also, I know that we'll need to reuse a lot of the child templates.

Comment: Also, Resources cannot be an empty list. I've tried that. `Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.`

Comment: Merge the templates if you have nothing to declare in one stack